# COMException(0x800A03EC) with interopServices C# in Excel

Tags: c#, office-interop, excel-interop

I am getting following exception when running an excel application that uses `C#`, Microsoft Office 2000, excel

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Item method
>   of PivotFields class failed    at
>   System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName,
>   BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData&
>   msgData)
>
> at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotFields.Item(Object Index)

Comment: I guess you could say more details about your question .

Comment: What's the value of `Object Index` in the call?

Comment: Not sure what the value of Object Index is as application is not failing on a specific value. This application was developed a long time ago and uses Microsoft Interop Services. When I run excel application it fails with the above message. It was working before so maybe a change in environment caused the issue.